# Debug viewer tool for Java

Tags: c#, java, .net

Do we have any Debug viewer free tool for Java that we use for .net (microsoft)?

If we write Debug.Writeline("Hello World"); that will print line in DebugView v4.78 tool.

I am trying to find that Java code also should print. Any tool available for java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discover log4j! Log4J is a logging library for Java, it will provide you with an ability to configure where to save log statements via different loggers.

For example, you can configure log4j to store all your log statements done via general-purpose logger into file `normal.log`, and log statements done via dedicated logger into file `very-special-errors.log`. If you want real-time monitoring and you on Unix, just say `tail -f very-special-errors.log`.

Here's sample `log4j.properties` file for that purpose:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, R
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=normal.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.specialLogger=ERROR, errorAppender
log4j.additivity.specialLogger=false
log4j.appender.errorAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.errorAppender.File=very-special-errors.log

log4j.appender.errorAppender.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.errorAppender.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.errorAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.errorAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

and here's sample Java code which uses this setup

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger normalLog = Logger.getLogger("rootLogger");
    private static final Logger specialLogger = Logger.getLogger("specialLogger");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        normalLog.info("Normal info");
        specialLogger.info("Special info -- won't be logged due to min logging level for specialLogger");
        specialLogger.error("Special error -- will be logged");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, however I would recommend to have a look to slf4j (which is just a facade) and put the log4j lib in the project. http://www.slf4j.org/.  After the log are properly in place in the code, I guess the question was more related to chainsaw ( as user1263942 said) in order to see / filter the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html)? This is Log4J specific though.

Comment: Chainsaw works with log4j, but can also process any regular text log file (see the VFSLogFilePatternReceiver section of the configuration example, available from the Welcome tab).  Also, there is a new developer snapshot of Chainsaw which provides a lot of bug fixes and new features, available here: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy